# Exe performs full link when Library changes, despite incremental linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, linker, incremental-linking

I have an MSVC++ project consisting of an executable, several own static libraries and some precompiled static third party libraries. The exe uses incremental linking in order to speed up build time.

When I change a .cpp file within the executable project, compiling + linking is very quick (<10s).
However, when I change a .cpp file within one of my own libraries, the executable project appears to be doing a *full* link against every library it uses.
I'm not so sure anymore if it is a full link in fact, but from the "vc90.pdb not found" Linker Warnings, I can tell that it links against some external libraries which have not changed at all.

Here's an example of the project structure:

- Precompiled third party libraries `ExtLib1`, `ExtLib2` and `ExtLib3`
- Own Library `MyLib`, using third party lib `ExtLib1`
- Own Exe `MyExe`, using `MyLib` and `ExtLib1-3`

Changing a .cpp file in `MyLib` would then lead to `MyExe` being linked to `MyLib`, `ExtLib1`, `ExtLib2` and `ExtLib3`, even if *Incremental Linking* is turned on.

A full link takes around 5 minutes in my project, so I'm asking: **Is there any way to re-link only the changed library?**

Answer (score 2):

This is a introduction to [incremental linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4khtbfyf.aspx). It lists situations that will cause a full link. One of them is "An object that was compiled with the /Yu /Z7 option is changed.", check if your MyLib caught it.

Comment: My libraries are compiled with /Yu /Zi.. I tried disabling precompiled headers for the library (i.e. removing /Yu) but it didn't change much. Maybe the linker is in fact trying to do an incremental link but links almost anything. Will have to investigate this further tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

When a static library changes there will always be a full link for the executable, at least in Visual Studio 2013, and you will probably get something like this in the output window:

```
2>Link:
2>  LINK : library changed; performing full link
```

Good news though: I did a quick test in Visual Studio 2015 and incremental linking seemed to work as expected.

Source: lots of experimentation and looking around, having had the same problem. Also, this: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/incremental-linking-and-multiple-projects.1431266/ , specifically:

> This is by design. We can't incrementally link when a static lib changes.
>   That was never supported before either.
>
> Ronald Laeremans, Visual C++ team

Edit - it's confirmed that VS 2015 has incremental linking when using static libraries: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/12/speeding-up-the-incremental-developer-scenario-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx .